# Точка останова в настоящее время не будет достигнута. Для этого документа не было загружено никаких символов

Tags: c#, visual-studio, dll

Я подключил к wpf проекту C#-библиотеку.dll
Мне необходимо в ней работать с точками останова, но они не работают.
Как загрузить эти символы?
Вот тут вроде как сказано, но в Debug->Window->здесь нет пунктов Mudules и Processes.

**UPD:**
Оказывается, открывать *Debug->Window->Mudules* нужно во время отладки. Тем не менее, напротив нужной мне библиотеки написано "Cannot find or open the PDB file"

Comment: не сможете работать т.к у вас нету иходного кода библиотеки , либо нужен файл от библиотеки.pdb

Comment: У меня исходники

Comment: тогда добавте в папку debug файлы исходников или поключите их к проекту

Comment: Добавлены и подключены

Comment: скомпилируйте библиотеку там будет файл .PDB укажите к нему путь